# Why 3d models are visible in Three.js without using any light sources?

Tags: javascript, model, three.js, 3d, light

**What I have**

As shown in the figure below i use Three.js library to create a WEBGL canvas and load a .gltf model in the scene using GLTFLoader.js.

[image: Demo Image]

**The Code I use**

```
//Add THREE Renderer
renderer_Main = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer_Main.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight); //Set Renderer Size

//Add THREE Scene
scene_Main = new THREE.Scene();

//Add First THREE Camera
camera_Main = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10000);
camera_Main.position.set(-2000, 500, 500); //Set camera position

//Add THREE Grid Helper
var size = 1000; //Value of Each Square Size 
var divisions = 60; //Value of Grid Divisions 
gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(size, divisions);
gridHelper.material.opacity = 0.045;
gridHelper.material.transparent = false;
scene_Main.add(gridHelper); //Add Grid in the Scene

//Add THREE Orbit Controller for the first camera
//Activate mouse events (L_Click, Scroll, R_Click) for moving around in 3D scene
orbitController_Main = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera_Main, renderer_Main.domElement);
orbitController_Main.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;  
orbitController_Main.saveState();

//Add Lights
//var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
//scene_Main.add( directionalLight );

//Add a model (.gltf file)
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load( 'models/model_environment/scene.gltf', 
    function ( gltf ) {
        //Add 3d model - file types : .gltf, .bin and (.png materials)
        selectedModel = gltf.scene; 
        selectedModel.scale.set(3,3,3);
        selectedModel.position.y = 45;
        scene_Main.add(selectedModel);
    }, 
    ...
);
```

**The Issue**

The issue is that when the objects are loaded are visible. Notice that I don't use any kind of Lights (commented). Also when lights are added, nothing changes. I tried using [THREE.DirectionalLight](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/lights/DirectionalLight) and [THREE.PointLight](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/lights/PointLight), but no luck. In case you wonder about the materials I use for this example is:

1) Cube:

```
camera_RT_Holder = new THREE.Mesh(
   new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 30),
   new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
);
```

2) .gltf model:

[Link of the model](https://sketchfab.com/models/485266e0d43e46a7bc7850d3d957571a?ref=related)

**Question**
If you have an idea what is going on please let me know.

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshNormalMaterial, this material is by default not affected by light sources.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure about this one. It's more clear now. Thanks for your answer, @BorisLi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The materials in your `glTF` file use the [KHR_materials_unlit](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/extensions/2.0/Khronos/KHR_materials_unlit) extension. Materials using this extensions are mapped to [THREE.MeshBasicMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial) which is an unlit material. That means it does not react on lights so it is visible even without any light sources in your scene.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your answer @Mugen87, it makes more sense now.